# how to set the request body in httpdelete android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, http-delete

Hi I need to pass some values in delete method. Some one please suggest me whether it is good to use HttpDelete (or) HttpUrlConnection and how to pass the values in delete method.

Comment: @hiphopdroid : `setParams` does not do what you think it does, or anyway is not related to the question

Comment: (these are `protocol and framework parameters.`)

Comment: HttpDelete does not take a body. You'd need to use HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: Ok sorry maybe I am wrong. I'll delete that comment right away

Comment: what do you mean by "pass some values"? How does the REST service look like?